# Getting values from XML Url Python

Tags: python, xml, dom

I have an account in https://es.besoccer.com/ and they have an api for getting data in a xml.
I have this code in python for print the values of the xml I need:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
doc = minidom.parse("datos.xml")
partidos = doc.getElementsByTagName("matches")
for partido in partidos:
    local = partido.getElementsByTagName("local")[0]
    visitante = partido.getElementsByTagName("visitor")[0]
    print("local:%s" % local.firstChild.data)
    print("visitante:%s" % visitante.firstChild.data)
    canales=partido.getElementsByTagName("channels")
    for canal in canales:
            nombre=canal.getElementsByTagName("name")[0]
            print("canal:%s" % nombre.firstChild.data)
```

The problem is thatthe XML of this site is a url so I don´t know how to read the xml  directly form the url. Other problem is that the xml contains some tags that are a link, and python throughs a error with that tags that contains a url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the API docs here: https://www.besoccer.com/api/documentacion
After you understand which API call you need to use, prepare the URL and the query arguments and use a library like [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) in order to read the data.

Once you have the reply (assuming it is XML based) - you can use your code and parse it.

Comment: Yes thanks, I have already solved the problem with that,using library requests i donwload the xml and then I read it

Comment: Great. If my answer helped you - feel free to vote up.